# Shuffle only fetched items in Backbone Collection

Tags: backbone.js

[The Backbone.Collection object](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection) proxies [Underscore's `Collection.shuffle()`](http://underscorejs.org/#shuffle) so all Backbone collections have the method `shuffle()`.

Underscore's shuffle works fine:
[image: -]

If I wanted to shuffle only the last 5 items in an underscore collection, it can be done with `slice()`:

[image: -]

You can also slice and shuffle a Backbone Collection:

[image: -]

But for a Backbone Collection that `fetch`es items multiple times from a database, I cannot seem to shuffle only the items that were fetched by the last `fetch` call, because items in the collection appear to be sorted by the order in which they are fetched, even after a slice-shuffle.

```
a.models  // say, [id:1, id:2, id:3]
a.fetch().done(function (data) {
    return data = _.shuffle(data)
})
a.models  // [id:1, id:2, id:3, id:4, id:5, id:6], still sorted
```

It appears that sorting inside the deferred object does not alter the outside collection in any way.

So, how can I sort only `n` items at the end of a Backbone Collection?

Comment: What about shuffling the data within the success callback of the fetch?

Comment: So you want to shuffle or sort?

Comment: @Jack Do you mean that `.fetch().done` callback in the example?

Comment: @Brian I see you solved your issue, what I actually meant was passing in a success callback to the [fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) call, something like `.fetch({ success: function (collection, response, options) {...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use parse function to shuffle returned data from server :

```
MyCollection.prototype.parse = function(resp){
  return _.shuffle(resp);
};

myCollection.fetch();
```

Comment: Oh snap, parse-level shuffle didn't occur to me. This looks promising... will test it out now.

Comment: This is unexpectedly genius. Thanks KiT!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a randomizing comparator to shuffle items as they are added to the collection.

```
comparator: function(a) {
  var rand = _.random(0, 1000);
  a.set({rand: rand});
  return rand;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pYyRp/